# Why does the UDP client port change on the UDP server

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I've been following a simple UDP server/client tutorial found [here](http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-winsock/), and I have a quick question about which port the client is connecting to the server.

From just viewing the code, it seems quite obvious that the server and client are connecting via port 8888:

Client.cpp

```
#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"  //ip address of udp server
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data
```

Server.cpp

```
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data
```

However, when I actually run the server and the client, the server says the client connected port is always different:

First run (Server Log):

[image: Note how the port changes]
*Note how the port changes from 8888*

Second run (Server Log)

[image]

*Note how the port changes again*

Why would the connected ports change from 8888?

Comment: Sending port != Receiving port.  I open a random port on my machine (54679) and send to you on port 8888.  You listen on port 8888 and can see my sending port (54679).

Comment: The client never calls `bind()` to set its local port. The comment is misleading.

Comment: They just copied the comment from the server to client, without changing it to reflect the different direction.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

The comment in the client is incorrect. They just copied that line from the server, but they should have changed it to:

```
#define PORT 8888   //The port to send outgoing data to
```

The client and server both put the port in a `sockaddr_in` structure. The server uses this structure in its call to `bind()`, which sets the listening port. The client uses it in the call to `sendto()`, so it sets the destination port.

Since the client never calls `bind()` to set a specific local port, the source port is selected arbitrarily from the ephemeral port range. Each socket gets a different port to distinguish them.

If a fixed port were used as the client's local port, you wouldn't be able to have multiple clients on the same machine, since there would be no way to know which client should receive an incoming packet from the server. So fixed ports are typically used for servers, which random ports are used on the client.

Answer (score 3):

When sending a UDP packet from one computer to another, there are two ports involved:  the port that the receiving computer's UDP socket is bound to and is receiving on (8888 in your case), and the port that the sending computer is sending from.  The port that you see changing is the port that the sending computer is using to send UDP packets from.  Since the sending computer never explicitly chooses a UDP port to bind to (i.e. it never calls bind() with a non-zero argument), the sending computer's TCP stack simply picks a currently-available UDP port to implicitly bind the sending UDP socket to, and this port may be different each time the sending program is run.

Answer (score 1):

8888 is the server port. The 5 digit port you see on logs are client ports created to eventually get data back from the server. This is an automatic and totally fine mechanism.